# How can I use zsh's zargs with list of commands?

Tags: zsh

How can I use zsh's `zargs` with list of commands?  I am aware of using something like `sh -c` but it seems like `zsh` would be able to do something more efficient.

I thought perhaps an anonymous function like:

```
zargs -I arg -- **/*.git -- function { cd $1/.. ; git log -1 --format=%cd } arg
```

but I get

```
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

Note: I am also aware I can solve this example with

```
zargs -I arg -- **/.git -- git -C arg/.. log -1 --format=%cd
```

but I'm looking for the more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zargs` is just a shell function, which can only take arguments, it's not a keyword in the syntax of that shell like `for`/`while`...

Here, you may as well use a loop:

```
for dir (**/.git(N/)) (cd -- $dir:h && git log -1 --format=%cd)
```

With `zargs`, you could use a function which you define beforehand:

```
log() (
  cd -- $1:h && git log -1 --format=%cd
)
zargs -I arg -- **/.git(/) -- log arg
```

If you want to inline the code in a generic way, you could define a helper like:

```
run() eval "shift; $1"
zargs -I arg -- **/.git(/) -- run '(cd -- $1:h && git log -1 --format=%cd)' arg
```

`zargs` is useful to break down long list of arguments to avoid the "arg list too long" limitation of `execve()`, but for usages like with `-I arg` here, I find it has little advantage over a `for` loop.

Comment: I can edit the post if you would like.  This is an excellent answer but the last one got me confused.  I think the helper should be `run() ( eval "shift; $1" )` because each cd changes the directory and so only the first cd succeeds.  And you need the `--` after the arguments it seems.  Plus, you added an extra `*`.  It should be `**/.git`.  I didn't know the for loop could be so elegant.  That is clearly what I should use and learn better.

Comment: @pedz, thanks. Good catches. I've hopefully fixed them now. I've kept `run` as is and added the subshell in the code passed to it instead.